# Selecting many columns/fields with lookup and junction tables. Out of memory exception

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, out-of-memory, entity-framework-6

I have a real estate database that is highly normalized for storing listing data. The primary data is spread between 3 tables (Listings, ListingDataCommons and ListingDataOthers) because of the enormous number of fields, then there are several junction tables for things like features, types, etc.

The users of the application use the GUI to define criteria/fields and the system will generate (using dynamic linq) the `Where`, `Select` and `OrderBy` statements. The problem is when the `Select` statement uses many of the junction and/or lookup tables, I get an `Out Of Memory Exception`.

Below is a strongly typed (for easier reading) example of a query that will throw the error. It will throw the OOM exception even if it is only returning a single record by the MLS Number.

```
var ListingResult = context.Listings
    .Where(a => a.MLSNumber == "123456" || a.MLSNumber == "654321")
    .Select(a => new
    {
        //--- select some data from the Listings table
        a.MLSNumber,
        a.DateLastUpdated,
        a.DateLastImageUpdated,
        a.Address,
        a.ZipCode,
        a.DaysOnMarket,
        a.DisplayOnInternet,
        a.DisplayReviews,
        a.AuctionYN,
        a.ListPrice,
        a.LeasePrice,
        a.SystemID,
        a.DateLastPriceChange,
        a.DateLastStatusChange,
        a.DisplayAddressOnlineYN,
        a.ListingID,
        Status = a.Status.Name,
        PropertyType = a.PropertyType.Name,
        PropertyStyle = a.PropertyStyle.Name,
        Country = a.Country.Name,
        State = a.State.Name,
        County = a.County.Name,
        City = a.City.Name,
        SaleType = a.SaleType.Name,

        //--- select some data from the ListingDataCommons table
        BathsFull = a.ListingDataCommon.BathsFull,
        BathsHalf = a.ListingDataCommon.BathsHalf,
        Beds = a.ListingDataCommon.Beds,
        FireplaceYN = a.ListingDataCommon.FireplaceYN,
        GarageSpaces = a.ListingDataCommon.GarageSpaces,
        HOAYN = a.ListingDataCommon.HOAYN,
        LotAcres = a.ListingDataCommon.LotAcres,
        NewConstructionYN = a.ListingDataCommon.NewConstructionYN,
        PetsAllowedYN = a.ListingDataCommon.PetsAllowedYN,
        PetsMaxWeight = a.ListingDataCommon.PetsMaxWeight,
        PetsMaxNumber = a.ListingDataCommon.PetsMaxNumber,
        RemarksPublic = a.ListingDataCommon.RemarksPublic,
        SqftHeated = a.ListingDataCommon.SqftHeated,
        SubdivisionName = a.ListingDataCommon.SubdivisionName,
        Taxes = a.ListingDataCommon.Taxes,
        TaxYear = a.ListingDataCommon.TaxYear,
        YearBuilt = a.ListingDataCommon.YearBuilt,
        AirConditioning = a.ListingDataCommon.AirConditioning.Name,
        ConstructionStatus = a.ListingDataCommon.ConstructionStatus.Name,
        HousingForOlder = a.ListingDataCommon.HousingForOlder.Name,

        //--- select some data from the ListingDataOthers table
        CDDFee = a.ListingDataOther.CDDFee,
        CDDFeeYN = a.ListingDataOther.CDDFeeYN,
        CondoFee = a.ListingDataOther.CondoFee,
        HOAFee = a.ListingDataOther.HOAFee,
        HomesteadYN = a.ListingDataOther.HomesteadYN,
        LotDimensions = a.ListingDataOther.LotDimensions,
        LotSqft = a.ListingDataOther.LotSqft,
        NumberBays = a.ListingDataOther.NumberBays,
        NumberBuildings = a.ListingDataOther.NumberBuildings,
        NumberFloors = a.ListingDataOther.NumberFloors,
        NumberHotelRooms = a.ListingDataOther.NumberHotelRooms,
        NumberOffices = a.ListingDataOther.NumberOffices,
        NumberRestrooms = a.ListingDataOther.NumberRestrooms,
        ProjectedCompletionDate = a.ListingDataOther.ProjectedCompletionDate,
        SchoolElementary = a.ListingDataOther.SchoolElementary,
        SchoolMiddle = a.ListingDataOther.SchoolMiddle,
        SchoolHigh = a.ListingDataOther.SchoolHigh,
        SizePorch = a.ListingDataOther.SizePorch,
        SizeBedMaster = a.ListingDataOther.SizeBedMaster,
        SizeBed2 = a.ListingDataOther.SizeBed2,
        SizeBed3 = a.ListingDataOther.SizeBed3,
        SizeBed4 = a.ListingDataOther.SizeBed4,
        SizeBed5 = a.ListingDataOther.SizeBed5,
        SizeBonusRoom = a.ListingDataOther.SizeBonusRoom,
        SizeDinette = a.ListingDataOther.SizeDinette,
        SizeDiningRoom = a.ListingDataOther.SizeDiningRoom,
        SizeFamilyRoom = a.ListingDataOther.SizeFamilyRoom,
        SizeGreatRoom = a.ListingDataOther.SizeGreatRoom,
        SizeKitchen = a.ListingDataOther.SizeKitchen,
        SizeLivingRoom = a.ListingDataOther.SizeLivingRoom,
        SizeStudio = a.ListingDataOther.SizeStudio,
        SizeStudyDen = a.ListingDataOther.SizeStudyDen,
        SqftTotalBldg = a.ListingDataOther.SqftTotalBldg,
        TotalUnits = a.ListingDataOther.TotalUnits,
        VirtualTourLink = a.ListingDataOther.VirtualTourLink,
        WaterAccessYN = a.ListingDataOther.WaterAccessYN,
        WaterExtrasYN = a.ListingDataOther.WaterExtrasYN,
        WaterFrontageYN = a.ListingDataOther.WaterFrontageYN,
        WaterViewYN = a.ListingDataOther.WaterViewYN,
        ZipCodePlusFour = a.ListingDataOther.ZipCodePlusFour,
        Zoning = a.ListingDataOther.Zoning,
        AWCRemarks = a.ListingDataOther.AWCRemarks,
        ArchitecturalStyle = a.ListingDataOther.ArchitecturalStyle.Name,
        CondoFeeSchedule = a.ListingDataOther.TimeFrame.Name,
        FrontExposure = a.ListingDataOther.FrontExposure.Name,
        Foundation = a.ListingDataOther.Foundation.Name,
        Furnishing = a.ListingDataOther.Furnishing.Name,
        HOASchedule = a.ListingDataOther.TimeFrame.Name,
        MobileHomeWidth = a.ListingDataOther.MobileHomeWidth.Name,

        //--- select some data from the junction tables (which in turn use lookup tables)
        AdditionalRooms = a.ListingAdditionalRooms.Select(b => b.AdditionalRoom.Name),
        AppliancesIncluded = a.ListingAppliances.Select(b => b.Appliance.Name),
        CommunityFeatures = a.ListingCommunityFeatures.Select(b => b.CommunityFeature.Name),
        ExteriorConstructions = a.ListingExteriorConstructions.Select(b => b.ExteriorConstruction.Name),
        ExteriorFeatures = a.ListingExteriorFeatures.Select(b => b.ExteriorFeature.Name),
        Financings = a.ListingFinancings.Select(b => b.Financing.Name),
        FireplaceDescriptions = a.ListingFireplaceDescriptions.Select(b => b.FireplaceDescription.Name),
        FloorCoverings = a.ListingFloorCoverings.Select(b => b.FloorCovering.Name),
        FuelTypes = a.ListingFuelTypes.Select(b => b.FuelType.Name),
        GarageFeatures = a.ListingGarageFeatures.Select(b => b.GarageFeature.Name),
        GarageTypes = a.ListingGarageTypes.Select(b => b.GarageType.Name),
        HeatTypes = a.ListingHeatTypes.Select(b => b.HeatType.Name),
        InteriorFeatures = a.ListingInteriorFeatures.Select(b => b.InteriorFeature.Name),
        KitchenFeatures = a.ListingKitchenFeatures.Select(b => b.KitchenFeature.Name),
        LeaseIncludes = a.ListingLeaseIncludes.Select(b => b.LeaseInclude.Name),
        MasterBathFeatures = a.ListingMasterBathFeatures.Select(b => b.MasterBathFeature.Name),
        ParkingOptions = a.ListingParkingOptions.Select(b => b.ParkingOption.Name),
        PoolFeatures = a.ListingPoolFeatures.Select(b => b.PoolFeature.Name),
        PoolTypes = a.ListingPoolTypes.Select(b => b.PoolType.Name),
        PropertyUses = a.ListingPropertyUses.Select(b => b.PropertyUse.Name),
        RoofTypes = a.ListingRoofTypes.Select(b => b.RoofType.Name),
        WaterAccessTypes = a.ListingWaterAccessTypes.Select(b => b.WaterType.Name),
        WaterExtraTypes = a.ListingWaterExtraTypes.Select(b => b.WaterExtraType.Name),
        WaterFrontageTypes = a.ListingWaterFrontageTypes.Select(b => b.WaterType.Name),
        WaterViewTypes = a.ListingWaterViewTypes.Select(b => b.WaterType.Name),
    })
    .OrderBy(a => a.MLSNumber)
    .ToList();
```

Is there a better way this can be structured? Even calling `.ToString()` on the query to view the generated SQL will throw the OOM exception.

**Update:**

In response to @Gert Arnold, can you further explain why the database is not normalized? Let's take for example the field for `Status` where I have `Status = a.Status.Name`. There is a table in the database called `Statuses`, which has 2 columns `StatusID` and `Name` and data would be something like `1|Active`, `2|Pending`, `3|Sold`. The field on the `Listings` table is `StatusID` that holds a reference to the `StatusID` field on the `Statuses` table. In order to get the actual name instead of the ID of the status, I must do `a.Status.Name`. This is the same exact structure for PropertyType, PropertyStyle, Country, State, County, City, SaleType.

Then for the `ListingDataCommons` and `ListingDataOthers` tables, these were created with a 1:1 relationship to the `Listings` table. They were created because there are hundreds of fields for a listing and instead of dumping them into one huge table, they were split up based on how often each field would be queried. In these tables, there are some columns that reference ID's of lookup tables rather than repeated string values as explained with the Statuses above.

Then there are junction tables such as `ListingAdditionalRooms` that has a 1:Many relationship where 1 listing can have many additional rooms. The `ListingAdditionalRooms` table (and all other junction tables) have 2 columns (ListingID | AdditionalRoomID) referencing the respective records in the `Listings` table and the `AdditionalRooms` table.

If this is one of the worst database designs you've seen, how do you recommend it be improved? Should I have one `Listings` table with almost 300 columns that stores string values repeatedly through the records? That does not seem like a good solution. Please briefly describe how you would go about doing it (the `Listings` table has millions of records). Not asking for a diagram, but just brief explanation.

To the suggestions, breaking it up into smaller chunks and requesting the data in 2 requests does seem to fix the issue (junction table data in one request, all other data in another).

Regarding this amount of data never being shown in any UI, that is incorrect. Though this query is only testing limits, this would absolutely be necessary to show a user the full details of a listing.

I look forward to your suggestions regarding the database structure.

Comment: Redesigning this is not something that can be done in a few comments. It requires lots of domain knowledge. One thing could be to have a features table, so a `Listing` can have a `Features` collection in stead of these numerous navigation properties at the bottom. But start discerning domain entities. Like, a `Listing` is nothing, it's not an *entity*. You're talking about Buildings (properties), rooms (or parts maybe), lots, prices, addresses, furniture, ... these should all be *entities* in your model, not *properties* (or fields) of one big bucket. Read about "ubiquitous language".

Comment: Would the `Features` table you suggest be an EAV pattern? I don't know much about DDD, but just can't see making things like a listing's `Price` or `Address` individual Entities instead of a property of a listing object, especially since each listing only has one price and one address. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: I don't know. Not as long as you can describe features as a "has-a" association. But, for that matter, EAV can be the only alternative when "things" have a continuously changing number of attributes, but I wouldn't resort to it too quickly. Addresses (and maybe prices) are usually modeled as *value types*. But I think your biggest challenge is to try and get this `Listing` object out of your system. Listing is an action. Pitfall #1 in DDD is modeling actions (verbs) as entities.

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework is choking in all the joins it's got to generate. Only in the `a.<some property>` parts you've got ***35*** different navigation properties! On top of this you access a large number of navigation properties in nested `Select` statements.

The core problem is that this is one of the worst database designs I've seen so far. The tables are just piles of unrelated and repetitive data. There is no normalization whatsoever.

Your only hope is to make a major overhaul of the data model, a new design, basically. Entity Framework is an ORM, object-relational mapper, so there should be something relational to begin with to make it a useful tool.

If the design is not in your hands there are two things you can consider:

- fetch the data in memory **piece by piece** and build the client-side objects from these building blocks.
- it must be possible to use **smaller models**. I can't imagine there is one UI view that will show all these data at once. Build dedicated view models for each view.